# Angular: mat-sidenav ignores autosize or mode on resize

Tags: css, angular, mat-sidenav

I am currently trying to implement the mat-sidenav into a project. Everything seems to work fine except for one situation: If I run the app locally in a browser, and I pull the window tab containing the app away and let it go (basically forcing it to resize a bunch of times), this causes it to open in a new and separate browser window. The current page its on looks alright too, the sidenav is to the side as expected.

However, when I navigate to another page, the content of that page goes underneath the side-nav. I tried setting autosize=true as well, and this helped in the sense that if I navigate out of the page and come back, it restores itself to what it is supposed to look like i.e. sidenav on the left and page content displaying on the right.

I have tried setting a timeout as well, and then forcing an open and close of the side-nav but that doesn't seem to do anything to help. Maybe there is a way to force refresh the other pages? The side-nav code is its own separate component, if that helps shed some light on the situation. Pasting what the code looks like:

```
<mat-sidenav-container [class]="mobRes?'project1-sidenav mob-sidenav':'project1-sidenav desk-sidenav'" autosize="true">
        <mat-sidenav #sidenav [mode]="!mobRes?'side':'over'" fixedInViewport="false" [opened]="!mobRes" [disableClose]="!mobRes"> 

...

</mat-sidenav>
</mat-sidenav-container>
```

EDIT: I ran some console.logs on the resize event and for some reason, after a few tries, it starts firing 3-6 resize events instead of 2, and this is precisely when navbar starts to overlap with the content. It works as expected (nav bar to the left and content to the right) before that. Another interesting thing is, in the chrome debugger, when it is working, the console.logs are grouped together (only one instance appears with the number next to it), but when it starts failing as in the case mentioned above, all of the console.logs appear on different lines, even though the message is the exact same. Note that there is nothing else is being written to the console at this point. 
Sorry if the edit wasn't helpful but I thought I would supply as many clues as I could as I explore this. If I figure it out I will post the answer as well, incase someone else runs into this.

Edit#2: This behavior start when I navigate away from the current page. So, to repro it, start the app, pull the tab out and resize a couple of times, then navigate away from the page (i do it by clicking on a link on the side nav bar)and come back, and repeat the resizing again, this time when you navigate to another page it will be covered, go to another page and come back, it will have reset itself to the intended positions

Answer (score 0):

as a workaround, I have added a toggle() on the resize event in the components .ts file. It is a bit jarring but it beats the content being covered up.